# Identity transformation in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this source XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
   <item1>
      <name>test</name>
      <price>160</price>
      <stock>4</stock>
      <country>Belgium</country>
   </item1>
   <item2>
      <name>Alfa</name>

      <price>140</price>

      <stock>3</stock>

      <country>Turkey</country>
   </item2>
   <item3>
      <name>Beta</name>

      <price>110</price>

      <stock>48</stock>

      <country>Holland</country>
   </item3>
   <product id="p1">
      <name>Delta</name>

      <price>800</price>

      <stock>4</stock>

      <country>Denmark</country>
   </product>
   <product id="p2">
      <name>Golf</name>

      <price>1000</price>

      <stock>5</stock>

      <country>Germany</country>
   </product>
   <product id="p3">
      <name>Alfa</name>

      <price>1200</price>

      <stock>19</stock>

      <country>Germany</country>
   </product>
   <product id="p4">
      <name>Foxtrot</name>

      <price>1500</price>

      <stock>5</stock>

      <country>Australia</country>
   </product>
   <product id="p5">
      <name>Tango</name>

      <price>1225</price>

      <stock>3</stock>

      <country>Japan</country>
   </product>
</root>
```

### And I want it to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
   <action>
      <name>test</name>

      <price>160</price>

      <stock>4</stock>

      <country>Belgium</country>
   </action>
   <action>
      <name>Alfa</name>

      <price>140</price>

      <stock>3</stock>

      <country>Turkey</country>
   </action>
   <action>
      <name>Beta</name>

      <price>110</price>

      <stock>48</stock>

      <country>Holland</country>
   </action>
   <action>
      <name>Delta</name>

      <price>800</price>

      <stock>4</stock>

      <country>Denmark</country>
   </action>
   <action>
      <name>Golf</name>

      <price>1000</price>

      <stock>5</stock>

      <country>Germany</country>
   </action>
   <action>
      <name>Alfa</name>

      <price>1200</price>

      <stock>19</stock>

      <country>Germany</country>
   </action>
   <action>
      <name>Foxtrot</name>

      <price>1500</price>

      <stock>5</stock>

      <country>Australia</country>
   </action>
   <action>
      <name>Tango</name>

      <price>1225</price>

      <stock>3</stock>

      <country>Japan</country>
   </action>
</root>
```

So the `<item1>` to `<item3`> turn into

```
<action>
```

And the `<product>` loses its attribute, and also turns into

```
<action>
```

Can somebody show me how to do this with XSLT? Because I have 2 different XSL's now. And I want to combine them to create just one XSL.

Thanks in advance

Comment: share the xslt you already have

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="product|*[starts-with(name(), 'item')]">
  <action>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </action>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="product/@id"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<root>
    <item1>
        <name>test</name>
        <price>160</price>
        <stock>4</stock>
        <country>Belgium</country>
    </item1>
    <item2>
        <name>Alfa</name>
        <price>140</price>
        <stock>3</stock>
        <country>Turkey</country>
    </item2>
    <item3>
        <name>Beta</name>
        <price>110</price>
        <stock>48</stock>
        <country>Holland</country>
    </item3>
    <product id="p1">
        <name>Delta</name>
        <price>800</price>
        <stock>4</stock>
        <country>Denmark</country>
    </product>
    <product id="p2">
        <name>Golf</name>
        <price>1000</price>
        <stock>5</stock>
        <country>Germany</country>
    </product>
    <product id="p3">
        <name>Alfa</name>
        <price>1200</price>
        <stock>19</stock>
        <country>Germany</country>
    </product>
    <product id="p4">
        <name>Foxtrot</name>
        <price>1500</price>
        <stock>5</stock>
        <country>Australia</country>
    </product>
    <product id="p5">
        <name>Tango</name>
        <price>1225</price>
        <stock>3</stock>
        <country>Japan</country>
    </product>
</root>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<root>
   <action>
      <name>test</name>
      <price>160</price>
      <stock>4</stock>
      <country>Belgium</country>
   </action>
   <action>
      <name>Alfa</name>
      <price>140</price>
      <stock>3</stock>
      <country>Turkey</country>
   </action>
   <action>
      <name>Beta</name>
      <price>110</price>
      <stock>48</stock>
      <country>Holland</country>
   </action>
   <action>
      <name>Delta</name>
      <price>800</price>
      <stock>4</stock>
      <country>Denmark</country>
   </action>
   <action>
      <name>Golf</name>
      <price>1000</price>
      <stock>5</stock>
      <country>Germany</country>
   </action>
   <action>
      <name>Alfa</name>
      <price>1200</price>
      <stock>19</stock>
      <country>Germany</country>
   </action>
   <action>
      <name>Foxtrot</name>
      <price>1500</price>
      <stock>5</stock>
      <country>Australia</country>
   </action>
   <action>
      <name>Tango</name>
      <price>1225</price>
      <stock>3</stock>
      <country>Japan</country>
   </action>
</root>
```

**Explanation**:

1. The identity rule copies every node "as-is".
2. We have two templates overriding the identity rule. The first template matches any `product` or any element whose name starts with the string `item`. It effectively "renames" the matched element to `action` by creating and outputting an `action` element.
3. The second overriding template matches any `id` attribute of any `product` element. This template has no body, which effectively "deletes" the matched attribute -- it is not copied/recreated in the output.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds easy:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="root/*">
    <action>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </action>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you want us to combine your existing code you need to post it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your Help Guys.. All answers I received worked. I now have to look for the best one to work for my project.
I now have a clue how to combine:)

Comment: @DennisvandenBrom and Martin. This answer is good, but a little bit too-rough. If the XML document is extended with other types of elements (children of the top element) they will all be renamed to `action` and none of their attributes will be copied in the output. This may not be the desired processing, so the current code will have to be modified. Do have a look at my answer -- the solution presented there has no such problem: it is more selective and thus more flexible and extensible.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just step through it and built it however you like. Ex:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no" />

    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <xsl:element name="root">
            <xsl:for-each select="node()">
                <xsl:element name="action">
                    <xsl:element name="name"><xsl:value-of select="name"/></xsl:element>
                    <xsl:element name="price"><xsl:value-of select="price"/></xsl:element>
                    <xsl:element name="stock"><xsl:value-of select="stock"/></xsl:element>
                    <xsl:element name="country"><xsl:value-of select="country"/></xsl:element>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```