# XSLT: Is it possible to blindly pass most elements yet transform specific elements?

Tags: xml, xslt

Given an xml file that has elements a, b, c and d is it possible to write an XSLT that will alter only element "c" and blindly pass all other elements?

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Person>
    <a>pass me blindly</a>
    <b>pass me blindly</b>
    <c>I need XSLT to convert me</c>
    <d>pass me blindly</d>
</Person>
```

Is it possible to have an XSLT that does the transform of "c" and yet all of the other elements are passed as they are in the source?

I would end up with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Person>
    <a>pass me blindly</a>
    <b>pass me blindly</b>
    <c>I've been CONVERTED!</c>
    <d>pass me blindly</d>
</Person>
```

And yes my knowledge level of XSLT is limited.

Comment: it is my hope that I do not need to specify in the XSLT every single element.

Comment: Yes. This is the basic mode of operation in XSLT. Search for "identity template" .

Comment: @Tomalak is this what you mean? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8679557/identity-transformation-in-xslt

Comment: Yes, exactly. The identity template makes an 1:1 copy of any input that does not have a more specific applicable template. So for your sample task you need two templates - the identity template, and one `<xsl:template match="c">` that handles the `<c>` case.

Comment: @Tomalak thank thank you thank you! The developer who was helping was (as I now understand it) using "Pull" and the resulting XSLT are painful. I kept asking myself if there was an easier way. This should do it.

Comment: If someone wants the credit, please feel free to answer and give an example. I'll mark accordingly.

Comment: Well this was easier than most XSLT questions. Kudos for getting it without any actual code samples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xml" href=".\XSLTFile1.xslt"?>
 <Person >
  <a>pass me blindly</a>
  <b>pass me blindly</b>
  <c>I need XSLT to convert me</c>
  <d>pass me blindly</d>
</Person>
```

The following XSL Transformation template will give you the desired result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="xsl:stylesheet" />
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="c">
    <c>I've been CONVERTED!</c>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Bill!  It should be possible to call a method to change to upper case instead of replacing the element with specific text. Right?

Comment: Yes, you can make a function call at that point … i.e. you do not need to hard-code the replacement text. The important part is to blindly copy everything, and then match the element you need to process, because it is XSLT you can do whatever XSL processing you need.

Comment: So i ran into a problem with XMLSpy. It added this `xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"` and for some reason that was inserted before the text `I've been CONVERTED!`

Comment: Instead of this `<c>I've been CONVERTED</c>` I'd get this `<c xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">I've been CONVERTED</c>`. I'm sure there is a logical explanation. Right?

Comment: you need   exclude-result-prefixes="xlink" in your stylesheet element: In the transformation I supplied, using your function namespace and prefix, the stylesheet element would look like this:   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" exclude-result-prefixes="xs fn">

Comment: If you're going to be doing a lot of XSLT stuff, I would recommend you get a hold of XSLT Programmer's Reference, by Michael Kay, and published by Wrox. My version was printed in 2000, so there could well be an updated version. Nothing beats locking yourself away for a couple of days and reading that book from cover to cover. I've not personally done any XSL for a good number of years; this answer is the result of my having been snowed in over Christmas 2000 and having nothing to read other than XSLT Programmer's Reference! After reading that you will be an XSLT (functional programming) guru.

Comment: Thanks for the advice and the pointers on excluding the namespaces. Reducing the size of the resulting XML file is very important in this context.

Comment: Bill is this the same author and style? [link](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0764569090/ref=sr_ob_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1537538639&sr=8-1) The reviews are not kind. Perhaps having it as Kindle where I can search will make up for the poor organization.

Comment: Actually this seems like THE book to get: [link](https://www.amazon.com/XSLT-2-0-XPath-Programmers-Reference/dp/0470192747)

Comment: This the exact [book](https://www.amazon.com/XSLT-Programmers-Reference-Michael-2000-05-15/dp/B01K13UGXG/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1537539966&sr=8-4&keywords=XSLT+Programmer%27s+reference), but the one's you have found would be more up to date.

Answer (score 1):

You have two possibilities to achieve what you want:

- a WhiteList approach and a
- a BlackList approach

The first one copies all nodes except for the white-listed which are processed differently:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="c">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('The node ',name(),' is being processed.')" />
  </xsl:template>  

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

The second one copies only the blacklisted nodes which should not processed further:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="node() | @*" priority="-1">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="a | b | d" priority="1">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>   

  <xsl:template match="*[parent::Person]" priority="0">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('The node ',name(),' is being processed.')" />
  </xsl:template>   

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: If the majority of the xml file is passed as is (several pages of elements) and only a handful of elements are to be modified (upper case) or dropped... which would you pick?

Comment: @D-Klotz: Isn't this question self-answerable? In this case the first option would be preferrable.

Comment: I wasn't sure your view of whitelist and blacklist matched my own. The way you worded it is still a bit confusing but that might be because I can't simply look at the example you've provided and digest it.

Comment: @D-Klotz: I just wanted to present you two alternatives of solving your problem. No pun intended. Sorry if I may have confused you.

Answer (score 0):

As you mention Altova you might also be able to use XSLT 3 (if you have a current version of Altova) and in XSLT 3 you can use `xsl:mode on-no-match` with the different values `on-no-match? = "deep-copy" | "shallow-copy" | "deep-skip" | "shallow-skip" | "text-only-copy" | "fail"`, see https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#built-in-rule and https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#declaring-modes, a declaration of

```
<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
```

would establish the identity transformation as the built-in rules for the unnamed mode. Then you would only need to add a template for that element you want to transform.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I am using XMLSpy to develop and debug but I'm using the XLST within a camel route of a wildfly 10.1 server. The other developers who are much more familiar with XSLT mentioned that I should target 2.0.  I'll dig and see if 3.0 is supported in that env as well.